# Getting access tokens from Mule 3

Tags: authorization, mule, mule-studio

I have a few simple flows in Mule: Database to Object to XML to HTTP, and vice versa. I set them up by configuring standard components, no problem there.

But to access the HTTP service, I need to send JSON to the customer's custom authentication service, retrieve the access token from the JSON response, and embed that into the URL at the HTTP endpoint.

An example of fetching the ticket using curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{'username':'xyz','password':'***'}" http://[url]
```

Being a newcomer to Mule, I have no idea where to fit this ticket service into the project. Should it, idiomatically, be a separate flow, a stand-alone class? How do I communicate with it from the HTTP component?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `<enricher>` element to interact with the token service in the middle of your main flow and store its result (`#[message.payload]`) in a flow variable (`#[flowVars.token]`).

Then you can use this retrieved ticket in the URL of the service you call, with the same MEL expression: `#[flowVars.token]`